# using dbms_refresh.refresh for only one MView

Tags: oracle

I have one Mview which is created already.
Now I want to refresh it using dbms_refresh.refresh() for evry 5 mins automatically.
( not using dbms_mview.refresh )

How this can be achieved ?

Comment: Original view is "REFRESH ON DEMAND FAST "

Answer (score 1):

Using the NEXT clause from the CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW statement, as described here:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302

An example can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_6002.htm#i2119766

Regards,
Rob.